# How come I cannot access an instance of a class defined globally inside another class?

Tags: python, class, oop, scope, global-variables

I'm trying to use the *ui* object within the Pawn class and I define and initiate *ui* outside everything, so it is global right? I've looked on here for questions relating to using variables outside classes but they seem to all refer to .self which I used in the UI class when initiating the Chess object.

The *#* represent bits of code I've cut out to help readability.

```
class UI:
    def ___init__(self):
        self.chess = Chess()
        # Calls main menu function which goes to a new game option

    def newGame(self):
        self.chess.startGame()
        while len(self.chess.pieces[0] == 2): # Which is index for Kings
            # Game, which is where *move* is called

class Chess:
    def startGame(self):
        self.chessBoard = Grid(9,9)
        self.pieces = []
        self.pawns = []
        for i in range(8):
            self.pawns.append(PawnObject(x,y,side))
        self.pieces.append(self.pawns)

class Grid:

    # Init method

    def cellOccupied(self,x,y):
        # This function checks if a place is empty
        # If empty, return false else, true

class Object:
    # Sets x, y, width, height


class ChessPiece:
    # Child of Object sets side (black or white)

class PawnObject:
    def move(self,newX,newY):
        if ui.chess.chessBoard.cellOccupied(newX,newY) == False:
            # Move

        # More code

ui = UI()
```

Traceback: https://gyazo.com/33e5b37b5290ff88433b29874c117ad7

Am I doing something blindingly wrong? I think the way I've programmed this all is very inefficient as I am still learning so is this a result of that? Thank you.

Comment: I think you've cut out too much information; we can't see what's creating the PawnObject and calling `move` - if the error actually is occurring there, which we also don't know for sure. Please at least show the full traceback.

Comment: @user3457241 - In your code excerpt, `PawnObject` is not a child of `ChessPiece`... hit the edit button under the tags of your question and fix that, please, then delete your comment saying that. Unless you think your code is written properly, in which case I'll let you know you're wrong... that might be part of your problem.

Comment: @DanielRoseman When the startGame() function is called, all the pieces are added to the list of pieces, which are added to the Grid. The move function is called within UI, in the main loop of a chess game when the player has decided to move a piece somewhere. Would it be helpful to show all the code? I've added the traceback to my post.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this cascading series of events all happens inside the initialisation function for UI; one class calls the next, all before the original `__init__` has had a chance to return. This means that the line that did that initialisation has not completed, so the `ui` variable *does not exist* yet.

You should try and move some of this out of that cascade. In particular, I can't see why the pawns should *move* as a result of initialising the UI class; that doesn't seem to make sense at all.

You should also consider why you need `ui` to be a global variable; seems more likely that it should be an attribute of one of the classes, perhaps Grid, and the pawn can reference it via that instance.

Comment: I changed it so mainMenu() is not called from init but after I initialise the ui and it worked. I never knew that the object didn't exist until the initialisation has completed. I'll take that in mind when I program things next time. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using `ui` in the body of a class, which is executed the moment the interpreter sees the class (and therefore before `ui` exists). You can only use it inside methods or functions since those are only executed when they're called. In other words:

```
class UI:
    def open(self):
        pass

class Chess:
    ui.open()  # <--- this causes an error because it happens before the last line does
    def startGame(self):
        ui.open()   # <--- this is OK

ui = UI()
```

Also, I think your message indicates that you wrote `global ui` somewhere which is only necessary if you're planning on assigning a new value to `ui`, i.e. `ui = something`. If you just want to use it, e.g. `ui.open()`, you don't need the global declaration. But removing it won't solve your problem.

You also need to correct

```
chessBoard = Grid(9,9)
```

to

```
self.chessBoard = Grid(9,9)
```

to make `chessBoard` an attribute of `Chess`, which you need to be able to say `ui.chess.chessBoard`.